# Can we create objects for abstract class in python

Tags: python-2.7

There is some confusion with abstract class in python, can we create object for abstract class in python?

Comment: https://zaiste.net/abstract_classes_in_python/

Answer (score 0):

No, abstract class can not be instantiated. You need to inherit the ABC class and define abstract methods to be able to have an object that implements the abstract class methods.

Comment: Thanks for the responding to my questions